# A JavaFX program to find out the mouse refresh rate v2

Tags: java, event-handling, statistics, gui, javafx

(See the continuation of this post in [A JavaFX program to find out the mouse refresh rate v3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286750/a-javafx-program-to-find-out-the-mouse-refresh-rate-v3).)

(This post is a continuation of [A JavaFX program to find out the mouse refresh rate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286668/a-javafx-program-to-find-out-the-mouse-refresh-rate).)

After adopting [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/286670/58360) by [@Reinderien](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/25834/reinderien), I ended up with this:

**`com.github.coderodde.javafx.mouseupdaterate.MouseUpdateRateFinder.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.javafx.mouseupdaterate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class MouseUpdateRateFinder extends Application {

    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();

        MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        
        // Add the event listeners:
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
                               listener::handlePressed);
        
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
                               listener::handleDragged);
        
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
                               listener::handleReleased);

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static final class MyMouseListener {
        private long dragStartNanoseconds;
        private int frameCounter;

        public void handlePressed(MouseEvent t) {
            dragStartNanoseconds = System.nanoTime();
            frameCounter = 0;
        }

        public void handleDragged(MouseEvent t) {
            frameCounter++;
        }

        public void handleReleased(MouseEvent t) {
            double durationInNanoseconds = 
                    System.nanoTime() - dragStartNanoseconds;
            
            double durationInSeconds = durationInNanoseconds / 1e9;
            
            String durationInSecondsString = 
                    String.format("%.2f", durationInSeconds).replace(',', '.');
            
            String frequencyString = 
                    String.format("%.1f", frameCounter / durationInSeconds)
                          .replace(',', '.');
            
            System.out.printf(
                "%d frames in %s s, refresh rate of %s Hz.%n",
                frameCounter, 
                durationInSecondsString,
                frequencyString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

Is there more room for improvement? Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LGTM.

---

Calling `.replace(',', '.')` seems a curious way to address Locale concerns.

Wouldn't you prefer to use the decimal format
[interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054217)
to obtain the desired `.` decimal point?
Then a single format string would suffice, instead of three.

Or perhaps the calling environment should be
[responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
for proper config, rather than this library code.