# A JavaFX program to find out the mouse refresh rate v3

Tags: java, event-handling, statistics, gui, javafx

(This post is the continuation of [A JavaFX program to find out the mouse refresh rate v2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286736/a-javafx-program-to-find-out-the-mouse-refresh-rate-v2).)

After taking [@J_H](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/286747/58360)'s suggestions into account, I ended up here:

**`com.github.coderodde.javafx.mouseupdaterate.MouseRefreshRateFinder.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.javafx.mouseupdaterate;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class MouseRefreshRateFinder extends Application {

    /**
     * Screen width in pixels.
     */
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    
    /**
     * Screen height in pixels.
     */
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    
    /**
     * Used in {@code DURATION_DECIMAL_FORMAT} and 
     * {@code FREQUENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT}.
     */
    private static DecimalFormatSymbols DECIMAL_FORMAT_SYMBOLS =
            DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    
    static {
        DECIMAL_FORMAT_SYMBOLS.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    }
    
    /**
     * The decimal formatter for duration.
     */
    private static final DecimalFormat DURATION_DECIMAL_FORMAT =
            new DecimalFormat("0.00", DECIMAL_FORMAT_SYMBOLS);

    /**
     * The decimal formatter for frequencies.
     */
    private static final DecimalFormat FREQUENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT =
            new DecimalFormat("0.0", DECIMAL_FORMAT_SYMBOLS);
    
    static {
        // Garbage-collect since unused from now on:
        DECIMAL_FORMAT_SYMBOLS = null;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();

        MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        
        // Add the event listeners:
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
                               listener::handlePressed);
        
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
                               listener::handleDragged);
        
        canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
                               listener::handleReleased);

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static final class MyMouseListener {
        private long dragStartNanoseconds;
        private int frameCounter;

        public void handlePressed(MouseEvent t) {
            dragStartNanoseconds = System.nanoTime();
            frameCounter = 0;
        }

        public void handleDragged(MouseEvent t) {
            frameCounter++;
        }

        public void handleReleased(MouseEvent t) {
            double durationInNanoseconds = 
                    System.nanoTime() - dragStartNanoseconds;
            
            double durationInSeconds = durationInNanoseconds / 1e9;
            
            String durationInSecondsString = 
                    DURATION_DECIMAL_FORMAT.format(durationInSeconds);
            
            String frequencyString = 
                    FREQUENCY_DECIMAL_FORMAT
                            .format(frameCounter / durationInSeconds);
            
            System.out.printf(
                "%d frames in %s s, refresh rate of %s Hz.%n",
                frameCounter, 
                durationInSecondsString,
                frequencyString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, I would like to hear about all possible improvements to my program.

Comment: What is the machine locale? This is kind of.. Not in the spirit of JH's suggestion, necessarily. What is the purpose of formatting decimals in a different style from the default locale?

Comment: Is your machine locale `fi_FI`? What is the value of `Locale.getDefault();`?

Comment: @Reinderien I will check my default locale tomorrow. Now tired.